# How to declare a zero initialized class member in C++?

Tags: c++

I have the following class in my `.hpp` file:

```
class user {
public:
    user(std::string username);

    static const user empty;
private:
    std::string username;
    std::uint32_t points;
    std::uint32_t level;
};
```

[According to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), an object can be zero initialized with `static T object;`. However, if this is done in a class, wouldn't that mean the `empty` user I declared above would be different each time it was included? I want the `empty` user to be the same shared across all files.

I was thinking about doing `extern static const user empty;` but I am not sure how I would actually define it in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: same as any other variable <type> <name> (<constructor args>);  `const user user::empty("")`

Comment: @UKMonkey I do not want to be calling a constructor. I want to have a zero initialized `user`.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Why do you want a "zero-initialised" user? What's a "zero-initialised" `std::string` for you? A `static` class member is different from a `static` variable / function.

Comment: `user::empty` is just declared here, you need a definition in a translation unit.

Comment: @MichaelSmith Zero-initialization is the first step for a static variable. After that, the default constructor is called before entering main.

Comment: Zero initialization is only a part of the initialization process. `user user::empty` will eventually be constructed however you defined it. And `static` class members are only initialized once, regardless of how many times the class declaration is included.

Comment: The documentation you linked demonstrated that it's done with blank constructor args.  syntax #2.1  But it also stated that:  `a std::string is "zero-initialized to indeterminate value, then default-initialized to ""` so you're probably not going to get what you think you're going to get.

Comment: This is a typical XY problem. I'd try and guess what you actually want is [`std::optional<user>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) and [`std::nullopt_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if this is done in a class, wouldn't that mean the empty user I declared above would be different each time it was included?

If by *"in a class"* you mean *within the class definition*, then the problem isn't so much being "*different each time*", as it is a violation of the one definition rule. There is always exactly one instance of a static member, and there must be one definition.

> I was thinking about doing `extern static const user empty;`

There is no need. You can keep using a static member.

> but I am not sure how I would actually define it in the .cpp file.

A source file is indeed exactly where the variable has to be defined. A variable definition has the following form:

```
type_name variable_name(constructor_arguments);
```

So, in the case of your static member:

```
const user user::empty("empty");
```

Or, if you choose to use the global instead:

```
const user empty("empty");
```